# Does the traffic between AWS Kinesis Firehose and s3 stay inside amazon network?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a lambda deployed into a private subnet. It is sending data to Firehose via a VPC endpoint. Firehose aggregates and sends this data to s3. Couldn't find it in the docs, does the traffic between Firehose and s3 stay inside amazon network? What if s3 is in a different region?